# Creating Jar archive gives "Could not find or load main class"

Tags: java, jar, manifest

```
$ cat Manifest.txt 
Main-Class: org.fenix.llanfair.Llanfair

$ cat org/fenix/llanfair/Llanfair.java | grep main
public static void main(String[] args) {
$ jar cfm Llanfair.jar Manifest.txt org
$ java -jar Llanfair.jar 
Error: Could not find or load main class org.fenix.llanfair.Llanfair
$ jar -xf Llanfair.jar
$ cat Llanfair/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF 
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.8.0_25 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: org.fenix.llanfair.Llanfair

$ ls Llanfair/org/fenix/llanfair/ | grep Llanfair
Llanfair$1.class
Llanfair$2.class
Llanfair$MenuItem.class
Llanfair$RecentMenuItem.class
Llanfair.class
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
```

I expect java -jar Llanfair.jar to start my application, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I do have a couple of files in lib/ which are on my classpath when I run the java code normally, do I need to include those?

My OS is Mac OS 10.11.1, if it matters.

Comment: Did you make sure that it is a RUNNABLE jar file?

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x   1 jbzdarkid  staff   185844 Nov 13 04:08 Llanfair.jar

Comment: when calling -java Llanfair.jar , try including the full oath to the jar. Example: -java C:\Llanfair\Llanfair.jar

Comment: $ java -jar /Users/jbzdarkid/Github/Llanfair_decompile/Llanfair.jar 
Error: Could not find or load main class org.fenix.llanfair.Llanfair

Comment: Can you launch the jar by clicking on it?

Comment: I can't see why Jar Launcher would function differently than the command line. No, it says the jar file could not be launched, and to check the console for errors.

Comment: Then the jar file must be currupt

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was missing the Class-Path: value in the manifest, why it would appear in this way is beyond me.

```
$ cat Manifest.txt
Class-Path: lib/ui.jar lib/jnativehook-2.0.2.jar
Main-Class: org.fenix.llanfair.Llanfair

$ jar cfm Llanfair.jar Manifest.txt org lib
$ java -jar Llanfair.jar 
<normal application output>
^C$ jar -xf Llanfair.jar
$ ls Llanfair
ls: Llanfair: No such file or directory
<manually extracted Llanfair.jar using Archive Utility>
$ cat Llanfair/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF 
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: lib/ui.jar lib/jnativehook-2.0.2.jar
Created-By: 1.8.0_25 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: org.fenix.llanfair.Llanfair

$
```

Edit: It's a little more complex. I was trying to include the jar dependencies in Llanfair.jar. This is not allowed because /reasons/. The above was working because I was running the jar in the same directory -- so lib/ui.jar was present because I was using it to build.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the file structure in `Llanfair.jar` is wrong.

Based on your comment `jar -xf Llanfair.jar` creates a structure like

```
Llanfair/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF 
Llanfair/org/fenix/llanfair/Llanfair.class
```

But the structure inside the jar file must be

```
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF 
org/fenix/llanfair/Llanfair.class
```

Comment: Jar -xf Llanfair.jar creates a folder called Llanfair, I don't cd into the folder.

Comment: @jbzdarkid This comment is not inline with your other answer `jar -xf Llanfair.jar`, `ls Llanfair` which lead to `ls: Llanfair: No such file or directory`. And then you `<manually extracted Llanfair.jar using Archive Utility>`.

Comment: Manual extraction creates that folder. Sorry for being unclear.