# How to resolve no such file or directory while creating jar file

Tags: java, executable-jar

Trying to create a `.jar` file called Llanfair.jar, using help from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33689262/creating-jar-archive-gives-could-not-find-or-load-main-class). Computer returns,

> org : no such file or directory.

```
$ cat Manifest.txt
Class-Path: lib/Sidekick.jar lib/JNativeHook.jar
Main-Class: org.fenix.llanfair.Llanfair
$ jar cfm Llanfair.jar Manifest.txt org lib
org : no such file or directory
```

Comment: Does the current directory contain the org directory?

Answer (score 0):

This would only occur if the org directory is not in the current directory.

Make sure you are in the directory that contains the org and lib directories then re-run the jar command.